# Setting PDF height in HTML/PHP page?

Tags: php, html, pdf, embed

I'm currently using this code to embed my PDF file on an HTML page:

```
<embed src="http://www.mywebsite.com/file.pdf" width="95%" type="application/pdf">
```

Is there a way that I can make the height be 80% of whatever the users current screen size is?  That way they can always view the entire PDF within the size of their screen?

Comment: this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Use this css:

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
}

embed{
    height: 80%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntQVw/